# Problems with GTK themes

Tags: themes, gtk, qt

A few weeks ago, I installed razor-qt on 14.04. everything was okay, but whenever i open a gtk application, it defaults to the elementary theme, as i had the pantheon de installed on it before. the window border is the gtk theme i want, as i use metacity, but even when i try to set the gtk theme in ubuntu tweak, it doesnt work, even as root. also i have installed the azenis icon theme, and it is okay in qt programs, but it defaults to elementary theme in gtk ones. my gtk and qt theme is delorean dark. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your gtk config files?  (e.g. `~/.gtk`)

Comment: @blujay - there is no .gtk in ~/. linuxfanatic

Comment: What is `~/.linuxfanatic`?  Try `ls ~/.gtk*`.

Comment: @blujay found it, will try now. thx

Comment: @blujay it just shows some directories, doesnt even mention gtk.

Comment: Look inside those directories.

Comment: @blujay bothing there. cant post more because not enough reputations to do chat

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it myself, due to a previous post on askubuntu the things you need to do is: 
install lxappearance (sudo apt-get install lxappearance)
then just set it to your desired icons and theme!.
(note: when you set the theme, set it to a gtk theme, not the qt one or things will go wrong.)